# Is Scimago or Scopus more reliable in terms of quartile classification?

Tags: journals

I have seen that, for example, a journal X appears in the Q3 quartile according to Scimago, but when I do a search using the sources and quartile from Scopus, this situation changes; putting the same journal in Q2. I have read that the differences between quartiles could have a marked variation between both sources. For example, in this situation, for CV purposes, which one should I consider, Scopus quartile classification or Scimago? And for not opening another thread which calculation is more reliable in terms of the academic quality of a journal?

Comment: Reliable about what to whom? As for 'CV purposes', as somebody who hires PhDs, I read a lot of PhD CVs - I'm not going to be impressed if somebody tries to tell me how good the journals are based on either rating - I know already.

Comment: Thank you @JonCuster for your reply, but I was a little bit dubious why the quartiles measurement are so different if we consider Scimago or Scopus

Comment: One presume they look at different factors, rate them differently, and weight them differently. Why do two people buy different cars?

Answer (score 4):

Your premise of one of these metrics being objectively better than the other is flawed: they are simply different. Counting citations is hard: should one also consider all the Facebook posts where the article was mentioned. If not, where to draw the line?

And the line they draw, by limiting citations to a subset of all sources, only considering the past five years or so - so while we are at that, why not add a few more bells and whistles?

Scopus' CiteScore is closer to the "naïve" impact factor calculations; Scimago's SJR is weighted by the "prestige" of the source the article was cited at. The comparison between different metrics could be found e.g. [here](https://www.elsevier.com/authors/tools-and-resources/measuring-a-journals-impact).

Like Jon Custer stated in the comments, they are just different (and, I might add, rather arbitrary!) ways to compare journals. For CV, this is entirely irrelevant; funding agencies would it explicit which rating to refer to so you would not have to bother yourself with that.